# jQuery: Dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of urls, and I'm wondering if there's a way to dynamically change the last digit of them.

```
    <div class="m_item">
        <a class="thumbnail_link" href="http://paraboladesignstudio.ipage.com/yahaira/fashion/fashion-slideshow/?thumb=0">
            <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail'];?>" title="<?php echo $image['title'];?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>"> 
        </a>
    </div>
```

The above code outputs certain number of ".m_item"s with the same "a href"s.

This is my jQuery code:

```
var i=0;
i++;

$(".thumbnail_link").each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace("0", i);
});
```

It changed all the urls to "..../?thumb=1"

How could I make the digit increase? I've tried .children with no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: At least try: `$(".thumbnail_link").each(function(i) {
    this.href = this.href.replace("0", i);
});` and remove your `i` declaration

Comment: beat you by 3 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the i and just use the index of the each() https://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$(".thumbnail_link").each(function(index) {
    this.href = this.href.replace("0", index);
});
```

Or you can do this in case there are other 0s in the url

```
$(".thumbnail_link").each(function(index) {
    this.href = this.href.replace("thumb=0", "thumb=" + index);
});
```

Comment: what happened when the url string have other "0" s ..?

Comment: From the way the OP asked, it seems there is only one 0, but you can always replace the entire thumb=0

Comment: Thank you, but then the url starts from 1, but it should start from 0. I tried i-1 but only got an error.

Comment: now the answer more close to his needs i think +1 for u

Comment: Just take 1 off from the index

Comment: @Huangism: Just found a problem... Now it starts from -1...!

Comment: @JaeeunLee in my code, index starts at 0, so if you want it to start at 0, then take out the index-1 and just use index. If you want it to start at 1 then do index+1

Answer (score 2):

It's doing that because `i` is only ever incremented once. It starts out as zero, then you bump it up to 1 with `i++`, and then you never change it again. Try this:

```
$(".thumbnail_link").each(function(i) {
    this.href = "http://paraboladesignstudio.ipage.com/yahaira/fashion/fashion-slideshow/?thumb=" + i;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

or if you want to update the last number, use this

```
$(".thumbnail_link").each(function(index) {
    this.href = this.href.replace(/([\d]+)$/g, index);
});
```